# How to configure Microsoft Encoder 4 Pro to stream http Live?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

Well, I'm developing an iphone app, I want to stream some videos, I have already done the player app, but due to my own controls it is posible to play a partial video, like 6second only, this is carrying me some problems cause when I seek or start my player at any second it goes till the 10 seconds closer, I mean if i want to go to the second 43 it goes to the 40... if i ant to go to the second 46 it goes to the 50 one so... I think this is a problem of HTTP live streaming or most from the encoding???

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HLS uses short media segments, so it's not unexpected that seeking would go to the start of the nearest segment. I think 10 seconds is the default. If you want finer granularity, you should decrease the [Segment length](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/854/live-smooth-streaming-for-iis-7---apple-http-live-streaming#configurepubpt). It's not possible to lower the segment length to less than the I-frame interval, which is generally around 2 seconds.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your comment to F3rr32r6. I'm not sure where you set the parameters for VoD content. You could always output a full file and segment it with a separate tool.

Comment: yeah I know that, the problem is that this function is set in the live streaming point, I am just encoding video files so I get them working but always with 10 seconds, Do you know how to modify it without a publishing point?

Comment: Yes, concatenate the files together and split it with a separate tool.

Comment: well finally i found it :) it is in the job transmuting template... thank you guys :) Here is the full guide  [http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/857/converting-media-to-on-demand-smooth-streams-and-apple-http-live-streams/]